# auto_increment primary key and linking tables (Mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am experimenting with Python connections to a MySQL database using MySQL workbench and I have a peculiar question.

I have a program running which displays a list of albums in stock, and then the user can choose which albums to add, then when the user confirms the order is complete, there is script to write and commit these new rows to the database.

My issue is that: when the lines are written to the **order_bridge** table, the **entryid** is unique for every row, and there is no way for this primary key to reference the **order** table.

I was thinking to make a trigger which insert the total cost of the order into the **orders** table, grab the new **auto_increment** value from the created row, and then update the newly written rows in **order_bridge** to all have the same **orderid**, but I haven't been able wrap my head around the process.

Here is how the tables are designed:

```
    create table albums
    (   albumid     int,
        albumname   varchar(100),
        artistname  varchar(50),
        price       int,
        quantity    int,

        primary key (albumid)
    );

    create table order_bridge (
         entryid        int auto_increment,
         orderid        int,
         albumid        int,
         quantity       int,

    primary key (entryid),
    foreign key (orderid) references orders (orderid),
    foreign key (albumid) references albums (albumid)
    );

   create table orders 
   (    orderid     int auto_increment,
        total       decimal(5,2),
        entrydate   datetime default current_timestamp,

        primary key(orderid)
   );
```

Comment: I think you should be inserting first into album and orders, and afterwards adding a new relationship to order_bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this at least once by actually inserting every customer that is in the site cart into the orders table.

This does three things:

1. prevents order ids that *complete* from being consecutive *(useless to some, useful for others)*,
2. provides a simple method for tracking cart abandonment statistics, and of course
3. allows you to have that unique order id when it comes time to record transactional data (like inserting selections into the `order_bridge` table).

Should you wish to only record the order row after the transaction finalizes, the order of operations should be:

1. insert order table info (including python calculation of total)
2. retrieve unique order table id
3. insert album rows
4. insert order bridge row

Comment: what security? The only real issue or infromation leak with consecutive id's might be that other poeple know how many orders you do in some period

Comment: besides that in the netherlands, we need to use consecutive invoice ids for a period anyway by law given by the belastingdienst (dutch word for tax authorities) **so you cant always avoid leaking this information to your customers if your country has laws like that**..

Comment: The OP will need to solve this in Python.  It doesn't seem like a Mysql question to me, but inserting the order when the person arrives, even if it has no data yet, is _a solution_.  The OP can determine which solution works for him - perhaps he will use your solution.